# What should I do compensate for the following kind of mistake in prayer?

Tags: salat

I made a mistake in the last sitting when I was reciting the dua that starts with, "Allahumma salli ala muhammadin ..."

I performed the last Salam (assalamu alaikum wa rahmatullah). Is my prayer valid? Should I perform the prayer again?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the durood shareef  (allahuma salli ala and allahuma barik ala) is Sunnah and if one makes a mistake in it, your prayer is still valid and you don't have to redo your prayer.

Sources: https://islamqa.info/en/173637
https://islamqa.info/en/65847